# Bridged TAP interface to virtualbox

Tags: iptables, virtualbox, openvpn, tunneling, tap

I need bridged TAP interface on client side of my VPN to virtual machine. I use VirtualBox 4.3.12.

But in Adapter Network options in `Attached to: Bridged adapter` I do not see my TUN adapter.

I have searched for this and I found some common [cases](http://www.eglug.org/book/export/html/3439).

But I do not find in my VirtualBox configuration:

> Step 11:
>
> At the VirtualBox startup panel, choose “Host Interface” and add “name of tap adapter″ to “Interface Name”.

Next I need to bridge absolutely all traffic from/to my VPN to this virtual machine, so there will not be any traffic routed to a real physical system.

Will it be possible to realize this via `iptables`?

I use Linux Debian 7.5.

My `OpenVPN` server configuration:

```
dev tun
ifconfig 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2
secret static.key
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
user openvpn
group openvpn
daemon
```

My `OpenVPN` client configuration:

```
dev tun
remote REMOTE_IP
ifconfig 10.1.1.2 10.1.1.1
secret static.key
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
user openvpn
group openvpn
daemon
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `OpenVPN` config files you are using `tun` interfaces, which operate at layer 3. That's fine, and probably what you want, but won't work with (ethernet) bridging because that requires layer 2 support.

You can solve your problem in two ways. Either:

- use `iptables` to route traffic from your tun interface to the host of your choice, or
- use `tap` interfaces in your OpenVPN config, which operate at layer 2.

For more information, take a look at the Bridging and Routing page on the OpenVPN wiki:
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need use second solution which operate only on layer 2. Have you any more detailed information about it please? I have found some examples with bridge-utils, so I am going to try it. But can my VPN ends until on virtual machine? Will it be better?